# Kotlin Coroutines Test fails: NoSuchMethodError: No virtual metod 'find'

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-instrumentation

I am in the process of migrating to kotlin coroutines test 1.6.x

This is a very basic test that fails:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import org.junit.Test

class HouseDaoTest {
    @Test
    fun insertAndGetHouseFromDb_success() = runTest {
        assert(1 == 1)
        assert(2 == 2)
    }
}
```

The error message I get when running this test is:

`No virtual method find(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;)Lkotlinx/coroutines/internal/ThreadSafeHeapNode; in class Lkotlinx/coroutines/internal/ThreadSafeHeap; or its super classes (declaration of 'kotlinx.coroutines.internal.ThreadSafeHeap' appears in /data/app/~~rVhSG062Jzg60YKAgWe6uQ==/my.packagename.test-Up28py4pbfA6CKyThEVObA==/base.apk)`

The line of code that hold the `find` method can be found here:

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/81e17dd37003a7105e542eb725f51ee0dc353354/kotlinx-coroutines-test/common/src/TestCoroutineScheduler.kt#L262

But I have honestly no clue what I am doing wrong, since this test is as basic as it gets. I found another SO post with this issue and it mentions that downgrading to 1.6.0 works, but not for me.

I also posted an issue in the respetive gihub: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/3503

Comment: The other day I had this same error for a different missing method that shouldn't have been missing. I cleaned the project and invalidated caches and that resolved it.

Comment: Thanks, treid that, but didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Got it and I feel stupid. The tests did not have access to the coroutine-core module.
I now set it up like this:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
androidTestImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.4'
```